# How to show that a matroid doesn't have any circuits if and only if the entire set is the only base?

Tags: matroids

The question is pretty self explanatory. I'm working with the definitions:

Matroid (Bases) $(E,\mathcal{B})$

1) No base is a subset of another base

2) $B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $e \in B_1$ implies $\exists f \in B_2$ st $B_1 - e + f \in \mathcal{B}$.

Matroid (circuits) $(E,\mathcal{C})$

1) $\varnothing \notin \mathcal{C}$

2) No circuit proper subset of another circuit

3) $e \in C_1 \cap C_2$, $C_1 \neq C_2$ implies $\exists C_3 \in \mathcal{C}$ st $C_3 \subseteq C_1 \cup C_2 - e$.

My idea was to try to prove that if we do have a set of circuits, we can construct a set of bases and vice versa. At this point I tried a couple of things, but to be honest am trying to do this without any proper intuition of what these sets are, and have no idea what a good approach would be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is impossible without some additional information ensuring that $\langle E,\mathscr{B}\rangle$ and $\langle E,\mathscr{C}\rangle$ are the same matroid, presented once in terms of bases and once in terms of circuits, and not two different matroids on the same underlying set $E$. In other words, you have to know the relationship between $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$.

If you know the notion of *independent set* in a matroid, this is straightforward: bases are maximal independent sets, circuits are minimal dependent sets, and $I\subseteq E$ is independent iff $I\subseteq B$ for some $B\in\mathscr{B}$ iff $\forall C\in\mathscr{C}(C\nsubseteq I)$. Starting here, it’s fairly straightforward to prove the desired result.

You may already have access to something better, but the [discussion of matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) in Wikipedia isn’t actually too bad. You might look especially at the **Definition** section and, for some simple examples, the **Uniform matroids** and the **Matroids from linear algebra** sections.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel there's a little more grounding to the problem now. For clarification, what do you mean with the notation $\mathscr{C}(C\subsetneq I)$?

Comment: @BallzofFury: You're welcome. As for the expression, you're missing part of it: it's $\forall C\in\mathscr{C}(C\nsubseteq I)$. In words, for each circuit $C$, $C$ is not a subset of $I$. That is, a set is independent if and only if it does not contain a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I see. So if $\mathscr{B} = \{E\}$, all $I \subseteq E$ are independent, so $C = \varnothing$. If it wasn't there would exist a subset of $E$ which isn't included in any subset of $E$ (all subsets are independent), so clearly false.

On the other hand if $\mathscr{C} = \varnothing$, $I \subseteq E$ is independent if for all $C \in \mathscr{C}$ we have $C \nsubseteq I$. This is vacuously true for all subsets, so the independent sets are all subsets of $E$. Therefore the only possible base (satisfying the subset property of a base) is the entire set $E$.

Does that sound about right?